# Postgres Indexes isn't being utilized

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

New to Postgres, and not very familiar with how RDBMS work in general. I read that, in certain cases, adding an index to a table speeds up query performance for databases. I tried it out with a table and did so (Postgres v11.2):

```
CREATE TABLE testtable(
    idString text,
    comment text
);


INSERT INTO 
    testtable(idString, comment)
VALUES
    ('1:2', 'some text'),
    ('12:2', 'blah'),
    ('2:2', 'other text'),
    ('1:3', 'blah'),
    ('33:2', 'blah');


CREATE INDEX myindex ON testtable(idString asc);
```

The guide I was reading said that, without an index, the database usually does a "sequential scan" of all entries until the query is found, but with an index, it does an "index scan". The guide says to see the query plan using "EXPLAIN",  so I do:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE myid = '1:3';
```

The output, however still seems to be a sequential scan:

```
                        QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on testtable  (cost=0.00..1.07 rows=1 width=64)
   Filter: (myid = '1:3'::text)
(2 rows)
```

I've checked using pgAdmin and see that `myindex` does exist, but I'm unsure why the database isn't using it? Is there something else that I'm missing/haven't done?

Comment: You don't have enough rows to make the index worthwhile.

Comment: Right this was just a test table, can't tell if your comment is just a general comment, or that's the reason the index doesn't exist. If the latter, how many rows does a table have to have before the index is utilized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Databases take many factors into consideration when deciding to use an index.

Your query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM testtable
WHERE myid = '1:3';
```

There are basically two reasonable approaches:

The first is to scan the data, and apply the `WHERE` clause to each row.

The second is to lookup the value in the index and then fetch the rest of the data.

Which is cheaper?  In your case, the *first* is cheaper.  Why?  Only one page needs to be moved from tertiary storage into memory.  Scanning the page -- after doing all the work of loading it -- is pretty cheap.

Using the index requires loading *two* pages, one for the index and one for the data.

Although database optimization is complicated, this is a simple example to give you a flavor of the different methods used in optimization and the trade-offs.

Comment: Still a bit confused. You're saying the second is cheaper, as in the database somehow decides this, right? If so, how does it decide that the second is cheaper?

Comment: @albert This is a huge topic in its own right, but basically, the database has a cost model associated with different physical operations such as scanning the table or seeking the index. It then considers various _physical_ operations that accomplish the same _logical_ operation and picks one with the lowest cost.

Comment: Ah ok I get it now, so the database determines which one to use. Then, as long as I create the index for the table, I can rest safe knowing that the database will use the index when optimal?

Comment: @albert In theory yes, and in this simple case almost certainly. In more complex cases, this so called "cost-based query optimization" mechanism may not work ideally, which is why this is a big topic! :)

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic That makes sense, thanks so much!